# Formulation of a nearly linear model

Tags: r, regression, modeling, nonlinear-regression

I try to fit a model of the following form
$$
 Y = (\beta X - Z)^+ + \epsilon,
$$
where $Y,Z \ge 0$ and $X,Y,Z \in \mathbb{R}$ and $(x)^+ = \max(x,0)$. 
Note that $Y,X$ and $Z$ come from a sample, especially $Z$ is not a constant.
I did this in R in the following way:

```
positivePart<- function(x){
  x[x<0]<-0
  return(x)
}
my.optim = nls(y~ positivePart(beta*x-z) , start = list(beta=5))
```

I am getting good results, this is not the problem.

My question: is there a name, a class for this kind of model? If so, which R function is the natural candidate to solve this problem, ie. to formulate the model in R? Thank you!

Comment: When writing a LS model, one should take care to insert the error term. Such models are called 'broken stick' models, though yours seems to be a special kind. It might be possible to rewrite it to be more like another kind (and this is why we need to take care about error terms!). These are related to linear spline models.

Comment: e.g. see Figure 1 [here](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0006320705000650). Another name for the general form is 'piecewise linear models'

Comment: @Glen_b could you please comment a bit more on what you mean by "insert the error term"? Thank you!

Comment: Furthermore @Glen_b: $Z$ is not a constant (I clarified this). Can it still be seen as a linear spline model?

Comment: Ah. I had thought it was a random variable, but just one - the same value for each observation. Yes, I think this changes things.

Comment: @Glen_b do you know of any reference for my problem? Does your comment with the error terms still apply. Or did you mean the distribution of the error terms?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know references, though I have seen similar problems to that before. Yes, the point about the error term matters if you're going to try to play around with the algebra. Alternatively, if you write the model as $E(Y) = ...$, that makes the issue clearer - though I still think keeping the error term explicitly in the model is less likely to lead one astray.

Comment: Would you like to post an answer to this, where you write out what you mean concerning the representation as $E(Y)= \ldots$ and concerning the error term? This would be helpful as I am not getting your ideas 100%. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This only addresses one small issue; it doesn't consist of a complete answer.

With a nonlinear least squares model, if we were to write $Y = f(X,Z)$, then unless the model actually passed through each point, our model is plainly nonsense. We don't mean what we write.

What we actually mean is something like $\operatorname{E}(Y) = f(X,Z)$, or (even better) $Y = f(X,Z) + \epsilon$.

When we come to do things with our model, failing to say what we mean leads to problems, as we lose track of what we mean - for example, consider the difference between:

$Y = \exp(\alpha + \beta x + \epsilon$) and $Y = \exp(\alpha + \beta x) + \epsilon$.

Without being explicit about what our model is actually saying, those two models would look the same - yet they should be estimated quite differently, and they have very different prediction intervals, for example.

(Similar issues apply to other models than nls ones, of course.)

Comment: Yes ... I have to write an error term ... otherwise the first formula is a pain in every statistician's eyes ;)

Comment: I found then notion of a Tobit model for this. It is a bit different as the $Z$ does not have a coefficient. Still I think Tobit models are the path do go.

Answer (score 1):

What I found in the meanwhile: this kind of problem is called a Tobit model:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tobit_model

package AER in R can handel them.

http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/AER/index.html